# sybase with clause returns errors

Tags: sql, sybase

I tried many syntax for the "with" with sybase 12

```
;WITH myCte AS (SELECT 1 AS FOO) SELECT * FROM myCte
```

I also tried nearly everything in this:

http://dcx.sybase.com/1100/en/dbusage_en11/commontblexpr-s-5414852.html

I tried with and without column names for the cte , with and without aliasing columns... etc
What is wrong? I keep getting

```
"Incorrect syntax near the keyword With"
```

I checked:

```
select name from master..spt_values where type="W" order by name
```

"with" is there, so it is known.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Your version of Sybase doesn't support `with`.  You can use a subquery instead.  The fact that `with` is a special word doesn't mean the syntax is supported.  A word could be a standard SQL reserved word (such as `select`); a word could be reserved for a future feature; or, the word could be used in an arcane command somewhere.

Comment: thanks. Is there no way to perform a recursive subquery without the "with" keyword ? I guess I'll have to use cursors.

Comment: Depends on the database, but I don't know how in Sybase.  You might want to post your problem as another question, to see if there is another way -- unless it is a hierarchical query.  In that case, use a cursor.

Comment: Well basically it is hierarchical. I am building a tree out of two columns. So yes i'll use a cursor. thanks :)